# Netbeans Platform and JPA

Tags: jpa, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have experience in JPA in Java EE for quite some time. Now I want to develop a desktop application with Netbeans Platform using JavaSE.

(I am not referring to the simple use of Netbeans IDE to code, but to use the [Netbeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html) to develop thick client applications using JavaSE.)

Can any one point me to a document which demonstrate JPA support to Nebeans Platform Applications? Googling was not helpful.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place for this kind of questions. However a simple search on the web would produce helpful results like: [Using JPA Support with EclipseLink](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/jpa-eclipselink-screencast.html) and [The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial - Adding Entity Classes and Session Beans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html)

Comment: I mean not the Netbeans IDE. I am referring to Netbeans Platform, where development of Thick clients using JavaSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is indeed appropriate.

There's a tutorial [on how to do this here](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html)